# Javascript site search on CD-ROM site without copy-and-paste?

Tags: javascript

Newbie here.

I want to create a site search for my offline website which will be on a CD.

Is it possible to use javascript to index the html pages automagically without me having to copy-and-paste every page into the script?

Thanks in advance for any assistance/guidance.

Answer (score 0):

No, with Javascript it's not possible to read files on the hard disc.
But you could use another language to automatically generate the index.